# Getting the duplicate values of 2 strings and counting them

Tags: java, android

Hi i need a little help im a bit confused on how to approach my issue i am creating a simple lottery game where in a user inputs 6 digits ranging from 1 to 49 then once he presses the button a 6 random number will appear below if he guessed them correctly a different display will happen.

My issue is i managed to create the program but only upto checking if all digits matched is there a way where in i can check if how many duplicates or matching values are there from string 1(user) and string 2(random generated) ?

Ex if the user gets 3 numbers correct it will display a different text even if the correct numbers is not in the same position

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eiho6.png)

Comment: Can you show the code you have already done?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Jdoedoe! Please explain what you have tried so far and where it failed, StackOverflow is not a coding service. I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question.

Comment: I have edited my post and added my code i know its simple but i can't really get the logic on how to compare those two strings in order to get my results

Comment: I have tried to go where in using hashset to remove the duplicate values, or using for loop into getting the duplicated ones but none of them worked so i wanted to ask if anyone knows a way around this thanks in advance

Comment: please do not post pictures of code. You might get [downvoted](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested loops and if expression with equals() method.
Check the following example where you have a counter that shows how many matches you have between the two array lists:

```
int counter = 0;

    ArrayList<String> one = new ArrayList<String>();

    one.add("23");
    one.add("10");
    one.add("40");
    one.add("9");
    one.add("49");
    one.add("25");

    ArrayList<String> two = new ArrayList<String>();

    two.add("1");
    two.add("49");
    two.add("28");
    two.add("10");
    two.add("3");
    two.add("45");

    for (int i = 0; i < one.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < two.size(); j++) {
            if (one.get(i).equals(two.get(j))){
                counter++;
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.printf("You have %s matches.", counter);
```

Of course you can do it with array lists of Integers instead of Strings.

Also I forgot to mention that if the numbers are in a string, like String numbers = "1, 34, 45, 23, 31, 18"; for example, you can use numbers.split(", ") to create an array and do the aforementioned steps over it. Then you can do the same with another array created from another string using split() method and regular expression.